# Hide Elementor widgets if there is no input in Advanced Custom Fields field

Tags: php, wordpress, web, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

so the question basically is that can I make an Elementor widget invisible automatically if there is a custom field that has no input?

Example: Heading element with dynamic tag associated from ACF becomes invisible on the page if the user hasn't typed anything in the ACF field associated with the element. By invisible I mean hidden on the page, then make it appear again and populated if the user later decides to input something there.

Thanks a lot!

I'm looking for a method that doesn't imply php coding. If there really isn't any solution then we can go to PHP, otherwise stick to some toggle button if possible for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

1st You need to edit your WordPress theme's `functions.php` file or a custom plugin. This involves PHP coding to check the ACF field value and conditionally print CSS to hide the Elementor widget.

for example:

```
function hide_elementor_heading_based_on_acf_field() {
    if (is_page()) {
        $field_value = get_field('your_acf_field_name');
        if (empty($field_value)) {
            echo '<style>.elementor-widget-your-heading-widget-class { display: none; }</style>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hide_elementor_heading_based_on_acf_field');
```

in this code replace your 'acf_field_name' with your ACF field name and `.elementor-widget-your-heading-widget-class` with the css class of your elementor widget.

Than 2nd Javascript for dynamic update: you will need javascript to dynamically show or (unknown) maybe hide the heading element based on the your ACF field value. so maybe you can do this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var acfField = document.querySelector('[data-acf-field="my_acf_heading"]'); // Adjust the selector to target your ACF field
    var elementorHeading = document.querySelector('.elementor-widget-heading'); // Adjust the selector to target your Elementor Heading widget

    function updateHeadingVisibility() {
        if (acfField && elementorHeading) {
            if (acfField.textContent.trim() === '') {
                elementorHeading.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                elementorHeading.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    }

    // Initial check
    updateHeadingVisibility();
```

The javascript selectors for the ACF field and the elementor widget need to be specific to your setup you maybe need to inspect the  output to get the correct selectors.

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there a way to call for ACF fields in general and not be specific? I have a field group of 147 fields which would involve a lot of code.